# How do you keep all of the items in a LinearLayout the same size while preventing them from going out of the bounds of the layout in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

**Goal**: I am trying to add between 50 to 75 RelativeLayouts to a vertical LinearLayout programatically. Each RelativeLayout has another LinearLayout inside with 2 ImageViews. And I want all of the images to be visible and the same size.

**Issue**:When I try to add them, only around 40 ImageViews are visible, and the rest are not shown.

- Each RelativeLayout contains 2 ImageViews with a wide image inside.
- All of the images on all of the ImageViews are the same height and width.
- It does't matter if the aspect ratio is lost, as long as all of the images are shown.
- Only the top LinearLayout has a margin. All of the views inside have no margin.

Diagram:

[image]

**My Adapter** (Does not extend any of the native adapters)

```
        private void LoadViews()
        {
            int amountOfRowsPerYear = 52 / mmCalc.amountOfWeeksInARow;

            for (int i = 0; i <= artifact.RowMetaList.Count; i += amountOfRowsPerYear)
            {
                cvWrapper = GetView(i, amountOfRowsPerYear);
                parent.AddView(cvWrapper);
            }

        }

        private RelativeLayout GetView(int position, int amountOfRowsPerYear)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            RelativeLayout convertView = (RelativeLayout)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ArtifactRowLayout, null);

            if (amountOfRowsPerYear != 2)
                throw new NotImplementedException("this mehtod can only accept 2 rows per year for now");
            else if (amountOfRowsPerYear == 2)
            {
                int first = position;
                int second = position + 1;
                Artifact.RowMetaData row = artifact.RowMetaList[first];
                Artifact.RowMetaData row2 = null;
                try {row2 = artifact.RowMetaList[second];}catch (Exception ex){}
                ImageView RowImageView = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.RowImageView);
                ImageView RowImageView2 = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.RowImageView2);

                RowImageView.SetImageBitmap(GetRowBitmap(row));
                try { RowImageView2.SetImageBitmap(GetRowBitmap(row2)); } catch (Exception ex)
                { RowImageView2.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone; }
            }
            return convertView;
        }
```

**ArtifactRowLayout.axml** (The Layout that is inflated in the GetView() method above).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/RowMainRL"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_weight="1.0">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/RowImageView"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/RowImageView2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**ArtifactDisplayer.axml** (id/ArtifactLinearLayout is where the views are being inflated).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ArtifactLinearLayout"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried many different attributes on all of the views, but I cant find a solution. More than half of the views end up out of bounds.

I also tried setting the exact height and width of each of the views programmaticaly but for some reason they are invisible after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to get them all shown, unless they're ridiculously tiny they won't all fit on the screen.

The correct answer to this is to use a ListView or RecyclerView so that you can scroll efficiently and display everything.  A bad but workable solution would be to dump it all into a ScrollView so it can scroll and display everything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The images are low fidelity and are also intended to be small. They are about 1080px wide, by around 42px high.